# Praying BOLDLY: Praying for personal achievement vs. praying for selfless achievement

Tags: prayer

I might have violated a ton of Christianity.meta regulations for asking something not specific but opinionated, but I figured this would be a good place to ask.

At Church, I was challenged by the series to [Pray Boldy](http://vimeo.com/36694694) and from bible study [Pray intentionally for something by circling around it and pray through it](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0310333024). Its about God would place a big dream in your heart, and challenges us to pray through it.

I am a student and I have daily challenges (i.e. loans, grades, scholarships, girls (lol), pride, friends, parents, etc) but is it selfish to pray for academic success? This would entail praying for being able to succeed in school, and make an impact in the corporate world, and being able to make a different in the lives around me. My biggest concern is picking something that is too easy, or not bold enough, or even too selfish and too "reactive". Should i stop praying for those? What are the dreams God has place in my heart???? I dont have any BIG dreams...

Comment: This question, as it is now, is not a good fit for our forum.  This is not a place to ask for pastoral advice.  I think this question could be modified to work, perhaps by just focusing on the basis and meaning of praying boldly or maybe concerning selfish prayers.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to check out this question: [How can I teach someone to pray?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7093)

Comment: Hello nikeunltd and thank you for your question.  
The [mission](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1380) of our site is to
answer factual questions about Christianity.  We are not able to answer 
[more personal questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/255).  We invite 
you to consult your local church, pastor, priest, mentor, or other trustworthy counselor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

God is concerned in the big and the small. If you take a look at the book of Proverbs, for example, you'll see that many of the bits of wisdom there aren't big life-changing issues but small, tactical day-to-day advice on dealing with people and situations. Since God is concerned on that level, praying on that level is appropriate. As Jesus said, God is concerned even with the birds, and your most minor school issues are more important than that. To say that the small matters don't matter actually betrays a distorted biblical worldview. God created the world and all that is in it. God is concerned that you get a job, that you work, that you be successful, that you find a spouse...or whatever he actually has planned for you.

However, that can be taken too far. I remember someone at college praying about if they should go eat mexican food one day. This isn't a bad idea because it is small but because it is irrelevant. There is nothing moral or immoral about mexican food (though I do consider fajitas of divine origin).

That being said, if you only live on the level of the small, then your vision may be too narrow. There is a truth in what you mention. Pray for a bigger goal in life. Pray that God will give you something bigger to focus on. And then pray about that too. But in looking for the big, you can't avoid the small. If you fail in your work, with girls, with school or with your parents then you will probably fail with the big.

My two cents.